# How do I work out how powerful a given machine is?

Tags: linux, performance

I'm confronted with a bewildering array of linux boxen.

How do I find out how many processors they have, how many cores, how much RAM they have, how fast their disks are, how heavily loaded they are by competing people  etc, etc?

Comment: Should have been moved to SU not closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want a static list, check for each characteristic with its own command and let your shell do the automation. That is, use /proc/cpuinfo for the CPU, /proc/meminfo for the memory, and /proc/loadavg for the computational load.
2. If you want to identify bottlenecks, have a look at `atop`.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command `sysinfo`

This returns a few things including

1. Number of Processes
2. Memory Size

[Full List here](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_sysinfo.htm)

There are also files such as `/proc/cpuinfo`, and `/proc/meminfo` that hold CPU and memory info.

Comment: I can't find this command, do you happen to know where it is on fedora 14?

Comment: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_sysinfo.htm

Comment: So I'd need to wrap it in a little piece of C? Has anyone already done this, cos if not it seems ripe for writing and packaging up as a .deb